# How can I have Screencast display keys pressed during transform operations?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'd like for the Screencast to display keys that are pressed after a transformation is begun. For example, after I select this cube and press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, I then press <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>, but neither the Z nor the 3 are displayed:

[image]

How can I get these keys to show?

Comment: You need to add addon first and then enable it after that it will show the key that you press on the screen. [Video show how to do it](https://youtu.be/ikZGjhw0i0E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling is a modal operation itself, just like the screencast keys. During the transformation, all events are consumed by that modal operator and never occur for the screencast keys addon. There is no controllable event bubbling like in browsers.

It could only be solved by a native screencast keys implementation through which all events would have to pass first.

Comment: Is there anyway perhaps Blender's undo history or something like that could be used to show it perhaps after the event? I assume no. Or could you have a keylogger kind of thing that would be like a blender addon?

Comment: btw, I assume anything even remotely resembling anything keylogger-ish is anathema in open source, but idk :P

Comment: You can actually check the operation log and try to reconstruct what was entered, e.g. `bpy.context.window_manager.operators[-1].properties.value`

Comment: Oh well, that's outta my league. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Found this

https://github.com/chromoly/blender-ScreencastKeysMod https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool

that can be installed by downloading the zip and added via the addons install button.

It correctly captures the modal events like numeric values entered while doing a grab.

Slightly more limited that the original addon with no clock and no nice mouse icon.